# How can I display post data on HTML page without using any template engine?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, post

How can I display POST data value from one HTML page on other HTML page without using any template engine ? Below is code fro posting data :

```
app.post('/RegistrationSuccessPage', function (req, res) {
   var uname = req.body.username
   var pwd = req.body.pwd
   var emailAddress = req.body.email
   postData = uname+","+pwd+","+emailAddress
   console.log(postData);
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/RegistrationSuccessPage.html",postData);
});
```

And following is HTML where I have to show the values:

```
<body>
        <div>   
        <form>
            <div align="center">
                <label>Below are the details</label><br><br>
                <label id="uname">Username *: (username_value_to_be_shown_here)</label><br><br>
                <label id="email">Email Address *: (email_value_to_be_shown_here)</label><br><br>
                <br><br>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: You cannot do that without some kind of template engine...or api with ajax requests and javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `username_value_to_be_shown_here` by `$USER` and `email_value_to_be_shown_here` by `$EMAIL` you can use string replacement like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
app.post('/RegistrationSuccessPage', function (req, res) {
   var data = {
       USER: req.body.username,
       EMAIL: req.body.email
   };
   fs.readFile( __dirname + '/RegistrationSuccessPage.html', 'utf8', function(err, content) {
      var result = content;
      for (var key in data) {
         result = result.replace("$" + key, data[key]);
      }
      res.send(result);
   });
});
```

if the $VAR is in more then one place you will need to use regex like:

```
result = result.replace(new RegExp("\\$" + key, "g"), data[key]);
```